# Show Export to excel button of list in main view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, excel

When I go to route Site Content --> My List , I can see export to Excel button

[image]

It works correctly as I want, problem starts when I publish my list, I want to see that Export to Excel in main view(published as Web Element) too, but no ribborn appears. What I need to do to show that button to public? Regards

Answer (score 0):

Create a page. Insert list as webpart. Set up view to show all fields you want to export. Edit webpart and change the toolbar type to Show Toolbar. This will provide the option to export to excel in one of the menus.

Comment: where is "Show toolbar", option? Regards

Comment: I found it, and I have it as "Show toolbar", but I still don't seeing nothing in published page